# How to include Underscore.js in angular2 project built using angular-cli

Tags: angular2-cli

I want to include underscore.js inside **angular2 project built using angular-cli**.
Till now I am unable to do so. I tried so far:

1- npm install underscore --save

2- tsd install underscore

3- script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"  , reference in index.html

4- inside system-config.js

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
var map = {
    'underscore': '../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
};
/** User packages configuration. */
var packages = {
    'underscore': '../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
};
```

5- import * as _ from 'underscore';

But underscore.js is not getting copied in 'dist' directory during run-time , and browser complain of not finding underscore.js. I think I am missing something at Point#4.
Any help is much appreciated as I am beginning learning angular2.
Please remember that this project is made by angular-cli, and not by any other seed project. Other than Underscore.js, project is working fine.

[EDIT]
package.json has "underscore": "^1.8.3" in dependencies

Answer (score 8):

Using Angular CLI 1.0.0-rc.1, the recommended solution is described here:

[Angular2 2.4 How to load external libraries sush as Underscore into angular2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194021/angular2-2-4-how-to-load-external-libraries-sush-as-underscore-into-angular2)

```
npm install underscore --save // save to dependencies: required to run
npm install @types/underscore --save-dev // save to dev dependencies: required in dev mode
```

Then in your component class:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
...
subtitle = _.head(['xyz'])
```

Alternatively, there is another way to load "static" scripts in angular-cli as described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#global-library-installation:

In .angular-cli.json, add it to the scripts array:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"]
```

This will load underscore.js, but this is not a good way to make it available for use in your typescript classes.

Answer (score 4):

install underscore using npm
Go to yourappname/src/typings.d.ts and add this line

`declare module 'underscore';`

then run ng build

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 full 3 file snippets

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "tsd": "^0.6.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'underscore':                 'npm:underscore',

      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },


      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'underscore':{
       main: './underscore.js', 
       defaultExtension: 'js'
       },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  },
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "underscore": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/underscore/underscore.d.ts#f0990e288ac73d593e982995947567aa2643b828"
  }
}
```

1- npm install underscore --save
2- tsd install underscore (if tsd not install first install that)
3) now do npm install
4) then npm start

Answer (score 1):

install underscore:

```
npm i underscore --save
```

in angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js",
         ...
      ],
```

after run command:

```
ng build
```

in component:

```
declare var _: any;
@Component({...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in your project a file called Package.json? 
If Yes, you can try to add this line

```js
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
```

in the dependencies of this file.

Modifications in system-config.ts

```js
var map = {

    "underscore": "node_modules/underscore",

  };

var packages = {
    'underscore':            { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var packageNames = [
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router-deprecated',
    '@angular/testing',
    '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages,
    paths: {
      "underscore": "/node_modules/underscore.js"
    }
  };
```

And to do a npm install after that.

Comment: Yes, package.json has this, but it is not updating system-config.ts

Comment: If you need to update system-config.ts, you must do it manually, as you did with package.json. And npm install, after all this modifications.

Comment: I tried your steps, but when running ng serve, it give error ' Cannot find module Underscore'. Can you please provide a working plnkr for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed a step? Did you remember to setup underscore in the "angular-cli-build.js" file? This step tells clingon to put underscore in the vendor folder (/dist/vendor).

Here's how I got underscore working.

1. Install underscore and typings:

   ```
   npm install underscore --save
   typings install underscore --save --ambient
   ```
2. Setting up underscore in "angular-cli-build.js":

   ```
   module.exports = function(defaults) {
     return new Angular2App(defaults, {
       vendorNpmFiles: [
         'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
         'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
         'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
         'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
         'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
         'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
         '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
         'moment/moment.js',
         'underscore/underscore.js'
       ]
     });
   };
   ```
3. Then underscore get compiled to the vendor folder (/dist/vendor), and now it's possible to point to this location from the system.config.ts file:

   ```
   const map: any = {
     "underscore": "vendor/underscore/underscore.js",
     "moment": "vendor/moment/moments.js"
   };

   /** User packages configuration. */
   const packages: any = {
     'underscore': {
       format: 'cjs'
     },
     'moment': {
       format: 'cjs'
     }
   };
   ```

Remember to use the hole path including the .js hope this helps :)

I did the same as with moment, from the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

Comment: I will definitely try this today.

Comment: Please let me know if there's anything I need to elaborate.

Comment: typings install underscore --save --global give me this error "typings ERR! message Unable to find "underscore" ("npm") in the registry."

Comment: You shouldn't install underscore global. just: npm install underscore --save

Comment: Again this error :: typings install underscore --save --global

Comment: @raju try, typings install --save --global dt~underscore

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular-cli, all I did was to add this line in `package.json`

```
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
```

and then I Run:
1. `npm install underscore --save`
2. `npm install`

and it worked...